# Extending a continuous function on compact sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

It is a standard fact in real analysis that if $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact and $f: K \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous, then there exists a continuous map $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $g = f$ on $K$. (cf. Chapter 1.2., Theorem 1, in *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions*).

Under what conditions does this remain true if the codomain $\mathbb{R}^m$ is substituted by an arbitrary topological space $X$? I am in interested in the following special case: Given a continuous function $f: K \to X$, where $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ compact, does $f$ admit an extension $g: CK \to X$, where $CK$ denotes the cone over $K$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such an extension $g$ exists if and only if $f$ is null-homotopic. In fact, homotopies $G : K \times [0,1] \to X$ such that $G(-,0) = f$ and $G(-,1) = const$ are in $1$-$1$ correspondence with maps $g : CK \to X$. Just use the quotient map $q : K \times [0,1] \to CK$ which identifies $K \times \{1\}$ to the tip of $CK$.

If one of $K, X$ is contractible, then all maps $f : K \to X$ are null-homotopic. This applies for example if $X= \mathbb R^n$ or $K = D^n$ = closed unit ball.